# Properties about weighted Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Take $w_1,w_2 \in L^1[0,1]$ to be such that $0 \leq w_1(x) \leq w_2(x)$ and define $L^2_w[0,1] = \{f:\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2w(x) \, dx < \infty\}$ with $$(f,g)_w = \int_0^1f(x) \overline{g(x)} w(x) \, dx.$$ Let $\{r_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that a family of exponentials $\{e^{\pi i r_n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ was such that its linear span is dense in $L^2_{w_2}[0,1]$, show that its linear span is also dense in $L^2_{w_1}[0,1]$.

My work: Note that $L^2_{w_2}[0,1] \subseteq L^2_{w_1}[0,1]$, so my idea is take any $f \in L^2_{w_1}[0,1]$ and approximate it by functions in the linear span of $\{e^{\pi i r_n x}\}$. We know that we can do this if our function was in $L^2_{w_2}[0,1]$. However I am stuck on even starting to construct a "candidate" sequence that will approach my $f$. I also know that if $(f,e^{i \pi r_n x})_{w_1} = 0$ for all $n$, implies that $f = 0$, then the span will be dense. But this characterization is probably not helpful since we are dealing with (potentially) complex functions.

How can I do this?

Thanks :)!

Comment: Are you sure you defined $L_w^2[0,1] $ correctly? You don't square $|f|$ in that integral?

Comment: @DionelJaime: Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: You need the assumption $w_1>0$ a.e.

Comment: @daw: I can only find some sequence that converges to $\sqrt{w_1/w_2} f $ in $L^2_{w_1}$. Could you kindly explain more?

Comment: @daw: I am not sure what you mean. I tried manipulating the quantity $\int |g_n - \sqrt{w_1/w_2}f| w_1 \, dx$ but then my sequence $g_n$ would no longer be in the span of my family.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: You should look through the book Functions with Disconnected Spectrum by Alexander Olevski and Alexander Ulanovski. The authors answer similar questions to this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in L^2_{w_1}$ be given. Take $n>0$. Then $f_n$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) := \max(-n,\min(f(x),+n))
$$
belongs to $L^2_{w_2}$ (since $w_2\in L^1$). In addition, $f_n \to f$ in  $L^2_{w_1}$ by dominated convergence theorem.

Now let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $n$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2_{w_1}}<\epsilon/2$. By the given density result, there is $g$ in the given linear span, such that $\|f_n-g\|_{L^2_{w_2}}<\epsilon/2$.
Since $w_2\ge w_1\ge0$, it follows $\|f_n-g\|_{L^2_{w_1}}\le \|f_n-g\|_{L^2_{w_2}}\le \epsilon/2$.